# How to insert data with sequence of number using axios in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

```js
axios.get("api/project_unit/" + this.$route.params.id).then(({data})=>{
(this.unit = data)

let count = this.unit.project_unit

axios.post("api/project",{
    project_unit: this.count + 1, <-------- here to working
    project_code:this.$route.params.id
    }) });
```

If I click save it will save on database '1' and if I click save again
It will insert '2'

> Controller

```
public function show($id){
return db::table("project")->where('project_code',$id)->get();
}
```

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Are you sending the request from a component? Why don't you just update `this.count` every time you send the request?

Comment: are you looking to perform multiple post with the `project_unit` having a sequential increment value (i.e.: 1,2,3,4)?

Comment: I'm trying to get data from database, I use `axios.get`  and I want to add +1 everytime user click save..